# Sliding Puzzle Help in random tiles

Tags: c#

I have a problem with creating a sliding puzzle. I'm trying to make a method to reset & shuffle all 15 buttons, but the problem is the random numbers are repeated.

When I write `bool[] usednum = new bool[array.length];` I get an error, so I increase the length of the usednum array .....

```
private void reset()
{
    int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
    int count = 0;
    Random r = new Random();
    bool[] usednum = new bool[50];

    for (int i = 0; i < usednum.Length; i++)
        usednum[i] = false;

    while (count < array.Length)
    {
        int temp = array[r.Next(array.Length)];
        if (usednum[temp] == false)
        {
            button1.Text = temp.ToString();
            usednum[temp] = true;
            count++;
        }

        temp = array[r.Next(array.Length)];
        if (usednum[temp] == false)
        {
            button2.Text = temp.ToString();
            usednum[temp] = true;
            count++;
        }

        temp = array[r.Next(array.Length)];
        if (usednum[temp] == false)
        {
            button3.Text = temp.ToString();
            usednum[temp] = true;
            count++;
        }

        temp = array[r.Next(array.Length)];
        if (usednum[temp] == false)
        {
            button4.Text = temp.ToString();
            usednum[temp] = true;
            count++;
        }

        temp = array[r.Next(array.Length)];
        if(usednum[temp] == false)
        {
            button5.Text = temp.ToString();
            usednum[temp] = true;
            count++;
        }

        temp = array[r.Next(array.Length)];
        if (usednum[temp] == false)
        {
            button6.Text = temp.ToString();
            usednum[temp] = true;
            count++;
        }
        /*.
        . 
        . 
        . to button 15*/
```

Comment: Should this question be tagged homework?

Comment: hmmmm i don't know what this question should be tagged with all i know that i need help .

Comment: Maybe I was unclear.  Is this homework?  If it is homework then you should tag it as such.

Comment: no it's not a homework , i just make the puzzle in java language and i am trying to do it in c#, sorry for the misunderstanding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just shuffle the array: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffling

A simple shuffle algorithm is (in pseudocode)

```
maxIndex = array.Length - 1
for index in 0 to maxIndex - 1
    swapIndex = random number between index and maxIndex
    swap (array, index, swapIndex)
```

Comment: shuffle the array is a genius idea, i did it and it is working thank u :)

Comment: I did the exact same thing, but reading on wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle) on the sliding puzzle, I found an interesting information about the solvability. It seems that half of the possible puzzles are unsolvable. So, doing a simple random like that won't work well for a sliding puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using a static array use a list

```
var array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
var unused = array.ToList();
var r = new Random();
while (unused.Count > 0)
{
       int c = r.Next(unused.Count - 1);
       int current = unused[c];
       unused.RemoveAt(c);
       //...
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering me , i did that but there's an error in that line     int current = unused[c];  << Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index >>

Comment: it should be int c = r.Next(unused.Count - 1);